# How to adjust the margins of a sidebyside tcolorbox environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox, sidebyside, tcbset

I have the following working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top = 2.54cm, bottom = 2.54cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[italic = true]{derivative}
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
  \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins, xparse, breakable, hooks, theorems}
\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bcases}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \tcbsidebyside[righthand ratio = 0.6,
        colback = blizzardblue!30!white, 
        colframe = blizzardblue!30!white,
        ]{{\bfseries #2}}{%
        \begin{gather*}
            \begin{cases}
                #3  
            \end{cases}
        \end{gather*}
        }\noindent
    }{
        \tcbsidebyside[righthand ratio = 0.6,
        colback = blizzardblue!30!white, 
        colframe = blizzardblue!30!white
        ]{{\bfseries #2}}{%
        \begin{gather}
            \begin{cases}
                #3      
            \end{cases}
        \end{gather}
        }\noindent
}}


   \begin{document}
        \bcases[Sphericals to Cartesians]{
        x & = r~\sin{\theta} \cos{\phi} \\
        y & = r~\sin{\theta} \cos{\phi} \\
        z & = r~\cos{\theta}
    }
    \end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

What I'm trying to fix is to minimize the horizontal space that `Sphericals to Cartesians` uses and to maximize (and to center) the space for the `cases environment`. Right know, this last environment is too at the right of the page, I need it more centered.

I already try without sucess changing the `righthand ratio, lefthand ratio` and adding `sidebyside align=right` in the options of `\tcbsidebyside` (this one gives error, idk why).

The answer to this question would be a code to replicate this (the figure is edited):

[image]

Thanks for read this and keep helping!

Comment: Your code don't give the 1st output. Your code outputs the text in serif, not sans serif font as displayed. Perhaps have you forgot `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` in preamble? Also, I don't obtain so much space between "Cartesian" and the brace. With the adding of the `\renewcommand` above, the blank has approximatively the length of the chars "Sphericals to C". Perhaps have you changed the margin size with the package **geometry**? And the equation label obtained is (1), not (1.20). Please correct your code in the question, so it correspond to the first image displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Done! Now you get the exact image displayed with the code given (sorry for the missing code). About why you get the space you're saying between "Cartesian" and the brace, that's something I don't know. Using only the code I wrote, I get the first image displayed

Comment: As you have changed the margins, the blank between "Cartesians" and the brace is a lot bigger yet, as displayed in the first image. It's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably don't want flush left aligned equations through the entire document, I don't use the global document class option `fleqn` here.

So I use the package `nccmath` which provide the environment `fleqn`. Notice that this package slightly reduce the vertical space before and after the displayed equation.

In this code, I use use the environment `fleqn`, **and in it, I use the usual environment `gather`** (and it's starred version).

Minor typographic adjustements: I have replaced `x & = r~\sin` (and so on) in your code by `x = r\sin` (and so on), so the spaces between elements are better adjusted (the space before and after the `=` is the same, and the space between *r* and "sin" is as between "sin" and "cos").

Note that `\sin` and so on don't take argument, so I have replaced `\sin{\theta}` by `\sin\theta`.

I have also corrected the conversion formula, but it is not important.

Finally, I have removed unused packages (physics, derivative, mathalfa, amssymb). About the `physics` package, it is probably better replaced by the new `physics2` (doc: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/physics2/doc/physics2.pdf) and some other packages (see the section 1.1 of http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/physics2/doc/physics2-legacy.pdf about problems with the `physics` package).

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top = 2.54cm, bottom = 2.54cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}
 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % >>> provide the fleqn environment

\usepackage{chngcntr}
  \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins, xparse, breakable, hooks, theorems}
\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bcases}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \tcbsidebyside[righthand ratio = 0.75,
        colback = blizzardblue!30!white, 
        colframe = blizzardblue!30!white,
        ]{{\bfseries #2}}{%
        \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{gather*}
                \begin{cases}
                    #3  
                \end{cases}
            \end{gather*}
        \end{fleqn}
        }\noindent
    }{
        \tcbsidebyside[lefthand ratio = 0.25,
        colback = blizzardblue!30!white, 
        colframe = blizzardblue!30!white
        ]{{\bfseries #2}}{%
        \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{gather}
                \begin{cases}
                    #3      
                \end{cases}
            \end{gather}
        \end{fleqn}
        }\noindent
}}


   \begin{document}
        \bcases[Sphericals to Cartesians]{
        x = r\sin\theta \cos\phi \\
        y = r\sin\theta \sin\phi \\
        z = r\cos\theta
    }
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comparison with the OP code (I have colored differently the two sides, by adding the line `bicolor,colbacklower = red!30!white,` between `colback =` and `colframe =` ):

[image]